# Master Page menu Orientation not rendering properly on postback

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

This is kind of a difficult issue to describe.  I have a site that uses Master pages.  I am basically using the default template for the masterpage that VS gives you when you create the project.  I have a asp:menu with the orientation set to Horizontal.  At the top of the page (in the master page) I have a dropdown list that allows user who have multiple job roles to be able to select which role they want to view at each time.  When they select a different role in the dropdown, the page(s) refreshes showing tha view for that page for the role.  One page has quite a lot of data with a couple telerik grids.  When this page refreshes, for a couple seconds while everything loads, the menu displays with orientation Vertical.  Once the grids load, the menu repaints horizontally.  I have no idea why this would be happening.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Rhonda

```
<form runat="server" id="mainForm">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img alt="" src="Images/logo_standard_48.gif" /></td>
                    <td><h1>WPR</h1></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Hello <span class="bold"><asp:Label ID="HeaderLoginLanID" runat="server" /> - <asp:Label ID="HeaderLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="ChooseRoleLabel" runat="server" CssClass="LabelText">Please select role:</asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList Width="150" ID="UserRolesList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserRolesList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Portal.aspx" Text="My Portal"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/StartChecklist.aspx" Text="On Board Application"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Search.aspx" Text="Search"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="Reports"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Help.aspx" Text="Help"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
         © 2011 . All rights reserved. | Version: 1.0.0.0 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: That would be Javascript that runs after or part way through the page load

Comment: I guess you answered the question that I asked.  My next question is how do I find the javascript and then fix it?

Comment: I should mention that I am not explicitly calling any javascript in the masterpage or the child page.

Comment: The javascript will be generated from the user controls you are using. If you view the source of the page you will see it. I personally don't like using controls for menus in this manner. I would recommend creating your own CSS based menus. With CSS you wont have the jumping.Sorry if that's not really the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I did as suggested and recreated my menu with a new css driven menu.  Problem solved.  Thanks Craig.

Comment: Great, glad I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think Craigs got the right idea. I had the same issue and I had to ditch the 'asp:menuitem' for normal HTML Li lists. I used the

> { display:inline; }

To make them appear horizontal and added lots of other CSS for similar effect and luckily this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Craig is correct, I kept the menuitem approach as it was bound to a SiteMapDataSource and leveraged the bootstrap menu.  In my case, the solution was to remove some addition javascript that appeared on the Site.Master along with the Master Page Menu